# DevExpress 8.3 and win7 x64

Tags: devexpress, windows-7-x64

Allow phonetic typing

I have an application that works perfectly on all versions of Windows that are 32 bit. In the application to use the Dev Express v8.3 controls. When I try to start the application on x64 win 7 shooting in the old and see that there is a problem with reading a common-dll containing refernce to devexpress.- Bad image exception. Is there any idea of ​​how effectively they can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should really ask DevXpress if that old version of their library fully supports x64 machines or not.

In general pure .Net managed code does work well on all supported CPU architectures as IL is compiled by the jit compiler at runtime.

Your bad image f. error is surely related to cpu architecture issues but are you 100% sure is from one of the devxpress files?

Comment: I don't know but i read over the net about this and people think the problem is in 3rd part dlls.

Comment: Could be but i doubt this is devxpress issue. do you have other dlls?